# How to split a tree into maxium subtrees with even nodes?

Tags: algorithm

Saw this question as follows and have no clue how to solve it:

Given an arbitrary tree, split it into as many subtrees as you can and the
number of nodes of the subtree must be even.

Any idea?

Comment: Please clarify: should all subtrees have even number of nodes or should we have a maximum number of the subtrees with even number of nodes

Comment: Based on my understanding, the question is to find as many subtree as possible by decomposing the original tree with the limitation that the subtree has to have even number of nodes.

Comment: So if the tree has odd number of nodes there will be no solution?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, I thought about this issue but the question doesn't give that information. After I read your question, it triggers me to think about splitting the tree with even number of nodes to subtree each with two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be, traverse through the tree, get count for each node. Add the node if the count is even.

```
List<Node> subTrees = new List<Node>();

int GetCount(Node root)
{
   if (root == null) return 0;
   return GetCount(root.Left) + GetCount(root.Right) + 1;
}
void BuildSubTrees(Node root)
{
   if (root == null) return;

   if(GetCount(root) % 2 == 0){subTrees.Add(root);}
   BuildSubTrees(root.Left);
   BuildSubTrees(root.Right);
}
```

I assumed it's a binary tree. If it's not, then instead of `left` or `right`, go through all it's `neighbors`.

Comment: This solution assumes that different subtrees can share nodes with each others. The original question doesn't mention this properties. So we may have to address both cases. 1> subtree cannot share nodes. 2> subtree can share nodes.

Comment: True, in that case before adding the Node to list you'll have to make sure the Node does not have itself or any children in any of the nodes and their children in the list. Basically another utility method to traverse through the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I would break this problem down as follows:

1. Traverse the tree. Each node within the tree represents a sub-tree of the main tree
2. Save the reference of each node of the tree in an array.
3. Traverse the array and determine the weight or number of nodes for each root.
4. Output/filter the sub-tree reference array (from step 2) where the weight is even.